# Dynamic Pivot using Temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-pivot

I have three query that are all building three separate tables. Procedures, DRGs and Diagnosis.  I do not know how many procedures, working DRGs or diagnosis a patient might have. However I only need to certain Procedure Codes, DRGs and Diagnosis Codes.  I have each entry ranked in the temp table.  Let's just work with one table for now as the answer will be the same for the other two.  Let's just work with the Diagnosis Table.

In the Diagnosis Table I have a field for Rank to it will just put in Dx_1, Dx_2, Dx_3 in the Dx_Rank field so I can just pull them out, but I do not know how many Dx there will be.  I need these all to be on one line.  So the output would be something like this.

Patient_Account, Visit_Key, Dx_1, Dx_1_Description, Dx_2, Dx_2_Dexcription, Dx_3, Dx_3_Description

From a table that looks like this

```
> Patient_Account, Visit_Key, Dx_Code, Dx_Priority, Dx_Rank, Dx_Desctiption  
> 123456789, #PAS203234, J20, 3, Dx_1, Left Hip is Broken 
> 123456789, #PAS203234, A32, 6, Dx_2, Left Knee is broken 
> 123456789, #PAS203234, R4786, 8, Dx_3, Left Ankle is broken 
> 987654321, #PAS435678, DF346, 2, Dx_1, Right Arm is broken  
> 987654321, #PAS435678, DT342.12, 4, Dx_2, Right Wrist is broken
```

So here I have two Patients and the output should look like this.

> ```
> Patient_Account, Visit_Key, Dx_1, Dx_1_Description, Dx_2, Dx_2_Description, Dx_3, Dx_3_Description
>
> 123456789, #PAS203234, J20, Left Hip is broken, A32, Left Knee is broken, R4786, Left Ankle is broken
> 987654321, #PAS435678, DF346, Right Arm is broken, DT342.12, Right Wrist is broken, , ,
> ```

So I thought I would do a PIVOT.  I set everything up and it does not give me what I want. I am getting the Dx_1 in the right Column, but when there is a Dx_2 it is the in right Column but it is on a separate line.   I wanted this all on one line as the final output will be going into Excel and I wanted to make it dynamic so if the max diagnosis I get is Dx_3 it would stop and not have 7 extra blank columns.  If I hard coded this to have 10 for each and then what happens when I finally get a patient that has 11 and I miss one because I have a limit of 10 Diagnosis.

Here is the script I have so far.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCEDURES_CPT') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #PROCEDURES_CPT
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCEDURES_CPT_PIVOT') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #PROCEDURE_CPT_PIVOT

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCEDURES_DRG') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #PROCEDURES_DRG
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCEDURES_DRG_PIVOT') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #PROCEDURES_DRG_PIVOT

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCEDURES_DX') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #PROCEDURES_DX
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PATIENTS') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #PATIENTS
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PATIENTS_FINAL') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #PATIENTS_FINAL

/** DEFINE TABLE AND PARAMETERS  **/

/** CREATE THE TABLE FOR THE PATIENTS  **/
CREATE TABLE #PATIENTS
(
        Patient_Account VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        Visit_Key       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)

/**  DECLARE THE VARIABLES FOR THE TEMP PIVOT TABLES THAT ARE NEEDED FOR THE THREE SECTIONS  **/
DECLARE @SQLPIVOT_CPT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLPIVOT_DRG AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLPIVOT_DX AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

/**  DECLARE THE VARIABLE NAME THAT WILL HOLD THE COLUMN NAMES LIKE CPT_1, CPT2, CPT_3, etc OR DRG_1, DRG_2,etc, OR DX_1, DX_2, DX_3, DX_4, etc  **/
DECLARE @PivotColumns_CPT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotColumns_DRG AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotColumns_DX AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


/** CPT CODES  **/

SELECT      pv.pt_id,
            pv.vst_key,
            pv.proc_eff_full_date,
            pv.prio_cd,
            'CPT_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pv.pt_id ORDER BY pv.prio_cd)) AS 'CPT_Rank',
            pv.proc_cd,
            pv.alt_clasf_desc,
            hrp.Procedure_Type,
            UPPER(pv.resp_pract_rpt_name) AS 'Surgeon'
INTO        #PROCEDURES_CPT
FROM        smsdss.proc_v AS pv INNER JOIN
            dbo.BETHESDA_HIGH_RISK_PROCEDURES AS hrp ON pv.proc_cd = hrp.Clinical_Code AND hrp.Report_Type = 'CPT'
WHERE       pv.proc_eff_full_date BETWEEN '10/01/2020' AND '09/30/2021'

/** DRG CODES  **/

SELECT      vv.pt_id,
            vv.vst_key,
            vv.end_full_date,
            vv.drg_no,
            UPPER(drg.DRGDesc) AS 'DRG_Description',
            hrp.Procedure_Type,
            UPPER(vv.adm_pract_rpt_name) AS 'Admitting Physician'
INTO        #PROCEDURES_DRG
FROM        smsdss.vst_v AS vv INNER JOIN
            dbo.BETHESDA_HIGH_RISK_PROCEDURES AS hrp ON vv.drg_no = hrp.Clinical_Code AND hrp.Report_Type = 'DRG' LEFT OUTER JOIN
            smsdss.DRGMstr AS drg ON vv.drg_no = drg.DRGNo  AND drg.DRGVers = 'MS-V38'
WHERE       vv.end_full_date BETWEEN '10/01/2020' AND '09/30/2021'

/** DX CODES  **/

SELECT      dx.pt_id,
            dx.vst_key,
            dx.dx_eff_full_date,
            dx.dx_type_desc,
            'Dx_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dx.pt_id, dx.dx_type_desc ORDER BY dx.prio_cd)) AS 'Dx_Rank',
            dx.prio_cd,
            dx.dx_cd,
            dx.clasf_desc,
            hrp.Procedure_Type 
INTO        #PROCEDURES_DX
FROM        smsdss.dx_grp_v AS dx INNER JOIN
            dbo.BETHESDA_HIGH_RISK_PROCEDURES AS hrp ON dx.dx_cd = hrp.Clinical_Code AND hrp.Report_Type = 'ICD-10'
WHERE       dx.dx_eff_full_date BETWEEN '10/01/2020' AND '09/30/2021'
GROUP BY    dx.pt_id,
            dx.vst_key,
            dx.dx_eff_full_date,
            dx.dx_type_desc,
            dx.prio_cd,
            dx.dx_cd,
            dx.clasf_desc,
            hrp.Procedure_Type 
ORDER BY    dx.pt_id,
            dx.dx_type_desc,
            dx.prio_cd
 
 /** PIVOT DX  **/
 SELECT     @PivotColumns_DX = COALESCE(@PivotColumns_DX +  ', ' , '') + Dx_Rank
 FROM       #PROCEDURES_DX 
 GROUP BY   Dx_Rank
 ORDER BY   Dx_Rank

SELECT @PivotColumns_DX

 SET @SQLPIVOT_DX = N'SELECT    pt_id, vst_key, ' + @PivotColumns_DX + ' 
                      INTO      #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT
                      FROM      #PROCEDURES_DX
                            PIVOT (MAX(dx_cd)
                                FOR Dx_Rank IN (' + @PivotColumns_DX + ')) AS tdx'
SELECT @SQLPIVOT_DX

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLPIVOT_DX

SELECT * FROM #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT
```

I am not getting any errors until I add in the last line a try a select from the Temp Table #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT to see what I have.  I get an error when I run the code that the Object is not Valid.  It is like the code is not being executed.  I created a simple test to see if it was a permissions even though I was not getting an error and I was able to create something.  I then took the output from that `SELECT @SQLPIVOT_DX` and that is when I was able to see my result and how I saw if a patient has a Dx_1 and Dx_2 that they are on two separate lines which is not what I want.  I am trying to get everything on one line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If my approach is not right please let me know.

Comment: This looks like SQL Server code so I have edited tags accordingly. Please update if it isn't.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you Nick

Comment: I also updated your title to something more meaningful

Comment: @RodgerDjr can you add data scripts as well to your question to see the output ?

Comment: Can you perhaps have a fixed number of `Dx_` columns (the extra ones will have a value of null) that way you can avoid dynamic SQL which compicates things immensely

Comment: I thought about that but I would need to have like 30 columns just to make sure I do not miss one, for the most part 5 would be enough but I wanted to try and make this dynamic if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get each Dx_Code of a Patient_Account in the same line, you need to `GROUP BY Patient_Account`, and use some aggregate function (like MIN() or MAX()) to get the Dx_Code and Dx_Desctiption.

Another way to make a **dynamic query:**

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(query_piece, '')

FROM (

(SELECT 'SELECT Patient_Account,' AS query_piece)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
    CONCAT('MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = ''', Dx_Rank, ''' THEN Dx_Code END) AS ', Dx_Rank, ', ', 
    'MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = ''', Dx_Rank, ''' THEN Dx_Desctiption END) AS ', Dx_Rank, '_Description, ')
FROM Diagnosis
GROUP BY Dx_Rank)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 'Visit_Key 
    FROM Diagnosis
    GROUP BY Patient_Account, Visit_Key;')) AS dynamic_query;
```

The result of the dynamic query is the query you have to execute to get the desired result:

```
SELECT Patient_Account,MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = 'Dx_1' THEN Dx_Code END) AS Dx_1, MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = 'Dx_1' THEN Dx_Desctiptio END) AS Dx_1_Description, MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = 'Dx_2' THEN Dx_Code END) AS Dx_2, MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = 'Dx_2' THEN Dx_Desctiptio END) AS Dx_2_Description, MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = 'Dx_3' THEN Dx_Code END) AS Dx_3, MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = 'Dx_3' THEN Dx_Desctiptio END) AS Dx_3_Description, Visit_Key 
    FROM Diagnosis
    GROUP BY Patient_Account, Visit_Key;
```

Output with the example data in your question:

| Patient_Account | Dx_1 | Dx_1_Description | Dx_2 | Dx_2_Description | Dx_3 | Dx_3_Description | Visit_Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | J20 | Left Hip is Broken | A32 | Left Knee is broken | R4786 | Left Ankle is broken | #PAS203234 |
| 987654321 | DF346 | Right Arm is broken | DT342.12 | Right Wrist is broken |  |  | #PAS435678 |

**Dynamic query in Sql-Server 2016** (without string_agg() function):

```
SELECT STUFF((  
        SELECT ' ' + query_piece  
        FROM ((SELECT 'SELECT Patient_Account,' AS query_piece)

        UNION ALL

        (SELECT TOP 100
            CONCAT('MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = ''', Dx_Rank, ''' THEN Dx_Code END) AS ', Dx_Rank, ', ', 
            'MIN(CASE WHEN Dx_Rank = ''', Dx_Rank, ''' THEN Dx_Desctiption END) AS ', Dx_Rank, '_Description, ')
        FROM Diagnosis
        GROUP BY Dx_Rank
        ORDER BY Dx_Rank ASC)

        UNION ALL

        (SELECT 'Visit_Key FROM Diagnosis GROUP BY Patient_Account, Visit_Key')) as x
        FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '');
```

Comment: OK let me go try this, I think this is just what I was looking for.  I did realize that is I want to select my table I have to add a line in my variable to get the data, I am going to work on adding in your code to mine.  Thanks!!

Comment: I am not seeing how I am looping through to get the different Dx_1, Dx_2, Dx3 in Dx_Rank.

Comment: It is not "looping", check the second UNION ALL in my dynamic query, it is grouped by Dx_Rank, so the result it is one row by Dx_Rank (you can restrict it with a WHERE clause), the result is two CASE statement by Dx_Rank (one for Dx_Code and the other for Dx_Desctiption). It is a different approach.

Comment: I am trying and I appreciate the help I am on SQL 2016 so I do not have the function STRING_AGG.  Is there something else I can use?

Comment: STRING_AGG() concatenates each dynamic query piece (row) to get the "desired" query into one field. You can use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` function instead of string_agg() function, I updated my answer.

Comment: PERFECT!!!  That works like a charm.  I can take that and add the additional fields I will need to the Procedures and DRG and the demographics.  Thank you again!!!!  I might have more questions but for now you HELPED Me figure this out!!!  Well you did the work I just learned something AWESOME!!!

Comment: I have  one more question.  When I run this I get just what I want except the order of the Dx Codes are not in order Dx_2 is first I tried to change the Order and nothing seems to work.  I am not able to do it when we build it as it is in the Union I am getting this error.  The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @RodgerDjr you are welcome! I updated the query to order by Dx_Rank values (using `TOP 100` in the subquery; if you have more than 100 Dx_Rank values you will need to increse this value). Don't forget to select the answer that best resolved your question (just one answer), furthermore you can vote more than one of them.

Comment: That was just what I needed thank you.  You really helped my elevate my game.

Comment: I am trying to add in the PROCEDURE AND DRG tables so I need to link up the vst_key I noticed that when a patient does not have a DIAGNOSIS I am getting an error as there is no Rank, so should I add in a Case when Dx_Rank is NULL to do nothing?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What error do you get? You should use `LEFT JOIN` to get patients without Diagnosis.

Comment: Nope No error I figured it out.  There was an issue when the dc_rank/cpt_rank is Null but I wrapped it in a case statement add the tables in and it all works fine now.  Thank you AGAIN!!!

Answer (score 0):

Good day, Unfortunately you did not provide all the related entities in order to reproduce your scenario and execute your full query, but the last main issue seems very clear

> I am not getting any errors until I add in the last line a try a select from the Temp Table #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT to see what I have. I get an error when I run the code that the Object is not Valid. It is like the code is not being executed.

The issue is that you create the temp table inside the scope of the execution of sp_executesql but you try to use it outside this scope and it is not exists there

Here is a simple full demonstration of the same issue

#### preparation

```
USE tempdb
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T
GO 
create table T(id int)
GO
```

#### Working sample where we create the temp table in the same scope that we call it

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT
GO 
SELECT * INTO #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT FROM T
GO
SELECT * FROM #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT
GO -- OK, since the temp table was created in the same scope as we call it
```

#### Error! Invalid object name '#PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT'

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT
GO 
DECLARE @SQLPIVOT_DX NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLPIVOT_DX = N'SELECT * INTO #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT FROM T'
SELECT @SQLPIVOT_DX
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLPIVOT_DX

SELECT * FROM #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT
GO -- Invalid object name '#PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT'
```

#### Optional solution is to call the table from inside the dynamic query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT
GO 
DECLARE @SQLPIVOT_DX NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLPIVOT_DX = N'SELECT * INTO #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT FROM T; SELECT * FROM #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT;'
SELECT @SQLPIVOT_DX
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLPIVOT_DX
GO -- Invalid object name '#PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT'
```

#### Back to your code

This is the same issue as in your code:

```
SET @SQLPIVOT_DX = N'SELECT    pt_id, vst_key, ' + @PivotColumns_DX + ' 
                      INTO      #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT
                      FROM      #PROCEDURES_DX
                            PIVOT (MAX(dx_cd)
                                FOR Dx_Rank IN (' + @PivotColumns_DX + ')) AS tdx'
SELECT @SQLPIVOT_DX

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLPIVOT_DX -- here you use select into to create the temp table

SELECT * FROM #PROCEDURES_DX_PIVOT --  and here you use it outside of the scope which it was created
```

Comment: I did provide a small sample of the data, but I cannot provided the table as that data is PHI.  I am not sure I understand your example.  You are inserting data into the same table you are selecting?  Is there a way to use the data that I have inserted into the temp table or do I need to create a table in my database and use it as my temp table then I can call it at any point and not worry about the scope.  RETHINKING - Then the table would not be dynamic and I am back to where I started.

Comment: I was able to manually run my query.  When I did I am getting a row for each Diagnosis.  Meaning Patient A I get a row with the Diagnosis 1 in Dx_1, Dx_2 is NULL then I get another row for Patient A with the Diagnosis 2 in Dx_2 and Dx_1 is NULL.

Comment: Hello @RodgerDjr, I still do not see sample tables and data. For example to the tables `smsdss.dx_grp_v` and `smsdss.vst_v` are used in your code. Note that `"table that looks like"` is not the way to provide the information. You should provide queries to create the relevant tables and to insert the sample data. If you cannot provide the real full structure then you should build your question around a fake simple table which can present the issue - sample table for the discussion. At this time I noticed your last question/issue which I could solve fast as I did.

Comment: If you can provide a full sample starting with DDL+DML to any related table(s) and your query which uses this sample table then I would love to take another look on the rest of the issue. At this time as mentioned I focused on your last issue in the thread :-)

Comment: Ronen, Yes Thank you I figured out that I would need to add the SELECT statement in the query string and then when it executes I would get my results.  So thank you very much for that, that helped a great deal to understand that part.  With that knowledge and what @nachospiu posted I think I am close.

Comment: You are most welcome @RodgerDjr . I am glad to hear that you solve it :-)  Have a great day

Comment: I want to thank you again.  I learned something from you about the scope and how I need to use it and why I was not getting the end results.  So thank you for that lesson,